# Create Database Snapshot for remote database on local machine

Tags: sql-server, database, snapshot

I am having a subtle problem in creating Database snapshot. I am connected to a remote database. I want to create a snapshot on my local machine. Is it possible or allowed?

I am typing the query below

```
> CREATE DATABASE SampleSnapshot ON ( NAME = 'Sample', FILENAME = 
> 'C:\SampleFile' ) AS SNAPSHOT OF Sample; GO
```

and getting the exception

```
Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

I am having following questions:

When i specify the path in query the snapshot will be created on local machine or server machine? If local machine then how to create the snapshot on server machine itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Generally Client/Server means you send instructions to the server. Which execute on the server. Which means that your C:\ is relative TO THE SERVER, not your client machine.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to create snapshot on local C:\ ? Are there any authentication or permission issues in doing that.

Comment: No. Or: save file on server, move it to client via file copy.